# Login an existing user in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I want to create a UI where i want to login the user which is already created in fabric.Tried using this(https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.3/balance-transfer) but as per the login request sample API, it is always creating a new user.

Any sample or ideas to login the existing users with fabric node SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The new user will be created if it does not find the same user in the wallet. Make sure when you create a user, you are keeping the identity in the wallet.

Comment: curl -s -X POST http://localhost:4000/users -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'username=Jim&orgName=Org1' I am using this for login,but it always create a new user, Is there anything to be added for login

Comment: the problem does not lie with the command for creating a new user but the backend where you check if the user already exists in the wallet.